# Access VBA Public Function - Variable for Control and Field?

Tags: vba, function, variables, ms-access

I want to set up a public function like the following:

(A)

```
Public Function CheckYNField(chkControl As Control, chkField As String)
If chkField = "Y" Then
    chkControl = -1
ElseIf chkField = "N" Then
    chkControl = 0
Else: chkControl = 0
End If
End Function
```

(B)

```
Public Function CheckYNFlipper(chkControl As Control, chkField As String)
If chkField = "Y" Then
    chkField = "N"
    chkControl = 0
ElseIf chkField = "N" Then
    chkField = "Y"
    chkControl = -1
Else: chkField = "Y"
    chkControl = -1
End If
End Function
```

The reason for this is, that I have a form, which has an underlying SQL table.  I have no control over the data, but I must represent it, for the ability to maintain it.  I have 10 fields, in the underlying table, which have a Y or N as their values.  The data types are actually nvarchar(10).  At the same time, I have to show these fields as checkbox controls, on the form, for ease of use.

The above code, is an attempt I am making to A - set the checkbox control to align with the current value in the table--> -1 = Y and 0 = N, and to B - update the table value, and switch the check box to checked or unchecked, from what it was, to the opposite, based on the onclick event of that control.

I want to make chkField and chkControl variables to the public function, that would be the table-field, and the form-control.  I can't seem to get the right syntax, and was hoping someone might have clarification on how to do this.

for the form load and current, I tried this:

```
CheckYNField Forms("frmFormNameA").Controls(chkCheckNameA), tblTableName.FieldA
```

for the on click, I tried this:

```
CheckYNFlipper Forms("frmFormNameA").Controls(chkCheckNameA), tblTableName.FieldA
```

I've tried some other methods, but doesn't seem to be working.  I'm doing something wrong, but I can't tell what.  Appreciate any tips!

---

**Edit/Update:**
I tried Kostas K.'s solution, abandoning the idea of making a public functions with parameters for the fields and controls.  I put the following, on load and on current:

```
With Me
    If .txtfieldboundtablefieldA.Value = "Y" Then
        .unboundchkA.Value = True
    ElseIf .txtfieldboundtablefieldA.Value = "N" Then
        .unboundchkA.Value = False
    Else: .unboundchkA.Value = False
    End If
End With
```

This is on a continuous form, so that it can show like a giant grid.  There are the identifying bound field controls, and then a series of these checkboxes, to display the Y/N true/false status of each of these particular fields.  I can't bound the checkboxes to the fields, because it changes the field value in the table to -1 or 0, and we need it to stay Y or N.  I added a bound text field, to hold the table/field value for each row (hence the call to a text box control in the above revised code).  The checkbox is unbound, and is there to display the field value, and allow the user to check and uncheck, so I can use on-click code to change the table field value between Y and N.

The above code is not seeming to show the correct checkbox value for each bound text field, based on each row.  It shows based on the row that currently has focus.  If I click on a row, where the table field is Y, all rows checkboxes on the form show true.  If I move to a row, where the table field is N, all checkboxes for all rows change to false.  I am struggling to just initially get 1 checkbox to show accurately, on every row of the continuous form, based on every record in the table.  This is a small table, like 30 records.  I really didn't think it would be so difficult to present this the way we need to.

Any ideas, how I could better do this?

Answer (score 1):

### Edit:

Set the Control Source of the checkbox to:

```
= IIf([YourYesNoField] = "Y", -1, 0)
```

In order to update when clicked:

```
Private Sub chkCheckNameA_Click()
    Dim yesNo As String
        yesNo = IIf(Me.chkCheckNameA.Value = 0, "Y", "N") 'reverse value
    CurrentDb.Execute "Update [YourTable] SET [YourYesNoField]='" & yesNo & "' WHERE [ID]=" & Me![ID], dbFailOnError
    Me.Requery
End Sub
```

---

You could try something this.

Check the Y/N field and assign the function's boolean return value to the checkbox (A).

On the checkbox click event, check its value and update the Y/N field (B).

```
'Form Load
Private Sub Form_Load()
    With Me
        .chkCheckNameA.Value = CheckYNField(![FieldA])
    End With
End Sub

'Click
Private Sub chkCheckNameA_Click()
    With Me
        ![FieldA] = IIf(.chkCheckNameA.Value = 0, "N", "Y")
    End With
End Sub

'True returns -1, False returns 0
Private Function CheckYNField(ByVal chkField As String) As Boolean
    CheckYNField = (chkField = "Y")
End Function
```

Comment: But this doesn't address the public functions.  I don't want to have to explicitly call every control/field, if I don't have to.  I like these subs you created, as they are elegant, but how can I parametize the controls and fields in a public function, so I can just call the function for every control and field?

Comment: See updated answer. Unbound checkboxes can be tricky in continuous forms. You click one and all get updated.

Comment: Thank you for continuing to help me.  Unfortunately that is having the same effect.  It's still making the checkbox the same on all rows, based on the value of the row I'm currently on.

Answer (score 0):

chkControl is a Control, so you need to access a property of that control.  Try changing your code to:

```
Public Function CheckYNField(chkControl As Control, chkField As String)
If chkField = "Y" Then
    chkControl.Value = -1
ElseIf chkField = "N" Then
    chkControl.Value = 0
Else: chkControl.Value = 0
End If
End Function
```

and then the same idea in your other function.

Comment: This wasn't seeming to do anything.  Please see my edits to my original post.  I am having trouble getting the checkbox to show accurately on each row of the continuous form, based on each record of the underlying table.  I've abandoned the public function idea, for now, so that I can focus on just getting the behavior to work properly.